# get records with passing multiple separated comma id from table where id is also comma separated in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table which one we have multiple category of each records with comma separated (event_type) we are passing comma multiple ids with comma separated. i found the query but its not giving result fine see below image of table structure. 
[Mysql Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aSDg.png) 
    enter code here

```
$query = "SELECT id,latitude, longitude, SQRT(POW(69.1 * (latitude - '".$lat."' ), 2) +  POW(69.1  ('".$lon."'  - longitude)  COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance FROM business_signup_details where event_type in (3,4) and business_details_approved = '1' HAVING distance < $distance ORDER BY distance";
```

Comment: Fix your data structure so you have a table with one row per "record" and one per `event_type`.  Comma-delimited lists are not the SQLish way to store values.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gordon told you have to change your database structure to store multiple value. Do normalization. Still if you want result you can use `like` keyword:

```
$query = "SELECT id,latitude, longitude, SQRT(POW(69.1 * (latitude - '".$lat."' ), 2) +  POW(69.1  ('".$lon."'  - longitude)  COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance FROM business_signup_details where event_type like '%3,4%' and business_details_approved = '1' HAVING distance < $distance ORDER BY distance";
```